# AWS CodeBuild - BuildSpec.yml - exported-variables are not resolving values

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, buildspec

I am trying to export a variable value from the CodeBuild Stage of AWS code-pipeline but the value is not resolving

Note: Windows container's PowerShell is executing the commands of buildspec.yml

Example: I am setting an Input environment variable named Client like below in the AWS CodeBuild project

[image]

and to export the same value I have modified my buildspec.yml like below

version: 0.2

```
env:
  variables:
    ClientEnv: $(echo $Client)
  exported-variables:
    - ClientEnv
```

but the exported value is expression not the resolved value

[image]

I have also tried passing variables but seems not working.

How I can pass the environment variables to exported-variables in such a scenario

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this your full `buildspec.yml`?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm dying to get A user-defined CodeBuild exported variable into my ApplicationStart.sh in CodeDeploy!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code as is:

```yaml
env:
  exported-variables:
    - Client
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `${Client}` in your buildspec.yml file

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the variable is Client as defined in the Env. Vars of CodeBuild project thenthe following is enough. You dont need to redefine the same variable in the **env->variables** section

```
env:
   exported-variables:
   - Client
```